# How to record macro in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

Currently I'm using PhpStorm and I want to make a macro like this:

```
echo "<pre">;
var_dump(**paste last copied value here**);
die;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can record a macro by using `Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording`.

You will have to type that all text manually and use clipboard as you would normally do. When finished recording you can assign custom shortcut to the freshly recorded macro and use it where needed.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

---

*But I do not think that you actually need a macro here.*

What you most likely need is code snippets .. which called **Live Templates** in IDEA-based IDEs -- it can work with clipboard content as well.

Once you create such Live Template .. you just type its' abbreviation in the text, hit the expand key (`Tab` should be the default one) and it will insert that code snippet instead.

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-templates.html

Comment: OK!! Working Fine Now, Thanks For Your Efforts